# Does exist ISO image set for testing lossless digital image compression

Tags: image, image-processing, compression, set, iso

So, does exist ISO(international standards organization) image set for testing lossless digital image compression? I have task to compare some algorithms for image compression and i need standard or de facto standard image set.

Thanks

Comment: If it's lossless, why do you care about the image set?  Shouldn't you be able to compare any images before/after and have them be precisely the same?

Comment: A standard set could be used to benchmark the compression ratios and compression and decompression speeds of various algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ISO, but yes there is a set.  The [Lossless Photo Compression Benchmark corpus](http://compressionratings.com/files/lpcb.ppm.zip), with these [benchmark results](http://www.imagecompression.info/gralic/).